# NextCloud неожиданно перестал работать

Tags: linux, сервер, centos, nextcloud

На сервере стоит Nextcloud. Все работало и вдруг неожиданно стала появляться ошибка, что нет прав для доступа к config. Поставил права 777. Ничего не изменилось. Переустановил nextcloud, теперь просто сервис недоступен. Думал, что все так же не хватает прав, дал всей папке nextcloud права 777. Не помогло.
Вот логи. Вроде все права на месте. Может кто знает, что может быть не так?

```
[Thu Jul 05 16:12:03.815771 2018] [:error] [pid 1685] [client 192.168.1.4:50974] PHP Warning:  fileperms(): stat failed for /var/www/html/nextcloud/data/nextcloud.log in /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Log/File.php on line 136
[Thu Jul 05 16:12:03.815830 2018] [:error] [pid 1685] [client 192.168.1.4:50974] {"reqId":"Wz22s8FAmylNvTIx6l6zFQAAAAA","level":3,"time":"2018-07-05T06:12:03+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.4","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"POST","url":"\\/nextcloud\\/index.php\\/heartbeat","message":"touch(): Unable to create file \\/var\\/www\\/html\\/nextcloud\\/config\\/config.php because Permission denied at \\/var\\/www\\/html\\/nextcloud\\/lib\\/private\\/Config.php#240","userAgent":"Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/67.0.3396.99 Safari\\/537.36","version":""}
[Thu Jul 05 16:12:03.815996 2018] [:error] [pid 1685] [client 192.168.1.4:50974] PHP Warning:  fileperms(): stat failed for /var/www/html/nextcloud/data/nextcloud.log in /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Log/File.php on line 136
[Thu Jul 05 16:12:03.816010 2018] [:error] [pid 1685] [client 192.168.1.4:50974] {"reqId":"Wz22s8FAmylNvTIx6l6zFQAAAAA","level":3,"time":"2018-07-05T06:12:03+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.4","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"POST","url":"\\/nextcloud\\/index.php\\/heartbeat","message":"fopen(\\/var\\/www\\/html\\/nextcloud\\/config\\/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at \\/var\\/www\\/html\\/nextcloud\\/lib\\/private\\/Config.php#241","userAgent":"Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/67.0.3396.99 Safari\\/537.36","version":""}
[Thu Jul 05 16:12:03.816132 2018] [:error] [pid 1685] [client 192.168.1.4:50974] PHP Warning:  fileperms(): stat failed for /var/www/html/nextcloud/data/nextcloud.log in /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Log/File.php on line 136
[Thu Jul 05 16:12:03.816145 2018] [:error] [pid 1685] [client 192.168.1.4:50974] {"reqId":"Wz22s8FAmylNvTIx6l6zFQAAAAA","level":3,"time":"2018-07-05T06:12:03+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.4","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"POST","url":"\\/nextcloud\\/index.php\\/heartbeat","message":"chmod(): No such file or directory at \\/var\\/www\\/html\\/nextcloud\\/lib\\/private\\/Config.php#244","userAgent":"Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/67.0.3396.99 Safari\\/537.36","version":""}
[Thu Jul 05 16:12:03.828689 2018] [:error] [pid 1685] [client 192.168.1.4:50974] PHP Warning:  fileperms(): stat failed for /var/www/html/nextcloud/data/nextcloud.log in /var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Log/File.php on line 136
[Thu Jul 05 16:12:03.828710 2018] [:error] [pid 1685] [client 192.168.1.4:50974] {"reqId":"Wz22s8FAmylNvTIx6l6zFQAAAAA","level":3,"time":"2018-07-05T06:12:03+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.4","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"POST","url":"\\/nextcloud\\/index.php\\/heartbeat","message":"fileperms(): stat failed for \\/var\\/www\\/html\\/nextcloud\\/data\\/nextcloud.log at \\/var\\/www\\/html\\/nextcloud\\/lib\\/private\\/Log\\/File.php#136","userAgent":"Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/67.0.3396.99 Safari\\/537.36","version":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

У пользователя, с которым работает Nextcloud, нет прав на доступ к этому файлу:

```
/var/www/html/nextcloud/config/config.php
```

Если вы ставили права на каталог, то по умолчанию права ставятся *только* на каталог. Ставить права вида `0777` на что угодно вообще - не самая лучшая идея. Правильней будет дать права для группы, пользователь из которой должен уметь читать этот файл:

```
chgrp www-data /var/www/html/nextcloud/config/config.php
chmod g+r /var/www/html/nextcloud/config/config.php
```

Comment: с nextcloud работает 'пользователь' из группы 'пользователь', все файлы в nextcloud/ настроены на эту группу и этого пользователя. Вот только файла config.php не было, есть только config.sample.php

Comment: если у него нет доступа, значит это не тот пользователь

Comment: вот [так](https://ibb.co/gUn9gd) выглядит каталог nextcloud'a. Есть какой-то файл, где мы задаем пользователя для nextcloud'a?

Answer (score 0):

```
find /var/www/html/nextcloud/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/html/nextcloud/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/nextcloud/
```